# Circular reference found while reading from Unix without copying to Local using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-integration, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I want to read .txt files from Unix location without copying it to local using Spring Integration.And this should be done in a continuous mode i.e as an when a new file comes it should be detected and read.

**Code:**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    public class SftpJavaApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(SftpJavaApplication.class)
                .web(false)
                .run(args);
        }
        @Bean
        public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {

            DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
            factory.setHost("ip");
            factory.setPort(port);
            factory.setUser("user");
            factory.setPassword("pwd");
            factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
            return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
        }
      @Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "stream",outputChannel="data")
public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer  transformer () {
    return  new org.springframework.integration.transformer.StreamTransformer("UTF-8");
            }

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "stream", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource() {
    SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template(), null);
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory("/test1/test2/test3");
    messageSource.setFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(),
                       "streaming"));
    return messageSource;
}



@Bean
public SftpRemoteFileTemplate template() {
    return new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sftpSessionFactory());

}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "data" )
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {


        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>"+message.getPayload()); //this prints the data in the file


        }

    };
}
```

}

**Dependencies :**

```
 compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:1.2.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector:1.2.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration")
    compile group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.44-1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-sftp', version: '4.3.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-file', version: '4.3.1.RELEASE'
    compile('org.kie.modules:org-apache-commons-lang3:6.3.0.Final')
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.4.192")
```

compile group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-core', version: '4.3.1.RELEASE'

**Stack Trace :**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to list files; nested exception is 2: No such file
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:104)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.list(CachingSessionFactory.java:218)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$6.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:417)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$6.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:413)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:435)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: 2: No such file
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2297)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1750)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1767)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.list(SftpSession.java:92)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: What does it mean Unix/Local? Do you mean reading a file from a remote server?

Comment: Yes.I want to read file from a remote server(Unix location).Somewhere it was mentioned that Sftp can help in that.It was tried by me but then it was copying the file in local and i had to read the file one by one.But i have to avoid that and read all  the available files in a  particular directory as and when any new file becomes available by avoiding xml

Comment: can you post your `configuration` file?

Comment: I am using the java configuration as we have been asked to avoid xml.The code above is what i am using.

Comment: Do not provide clarifications and additional information in comments. Edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Spring Integration `4.3`, the remote files support (FTP/SFTP) provides `streaming` adapters:

```
<int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
            channel="ftpChannel"
            session-factory="sessionFactory"
            filename-pattern="*.txt"
            filename-regex=".*\.txt"
            filter="filter"
            remote-file-separator="/"
            comparator="comparator"
            remote-directory-expression="'foo/bar'">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
</int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/whats-new.html#_ftp_sftp_streaming_inbound_channel_adapters

But! We can't do that "in a continuous mode" because (S)FTP isn't event-driven protocol. So, we still should to poll remote directory periodically.

If you really know some way to make it listening for some events in the remote directory, we would be very pleased to have such a component in Spring Integration out-of-the-box.

**EDIT**

When you upgrade your dependencies for Spring Integration, please be sure that all the modules are in the same version, you versioning isn't good.

The `spring-integration-file` should be `4.3.1.RELEASE`, too.

OTOH you don't need it at all. It is a transitive dependency of `spring-integration-sftp`.
As well as you don't need `spring-integration-core` because it is transitive dependency of all of them.

**EDIT2**

> I would only like to know the significance of the word "Streaming " used in the filter .It as such did not prevent file from reading at my end. But for knowledge purpose i would like to know

The purpose of `Streaming` adapters to let a target application do not create the *local* file copy. Just read data from the remote source directly in the memory. So, that's how you can still read file, but that is a remote one. Isn't it ?

Regarding error on PCF.

That would be great to share the StackTrace on the matter with us.
From other side, please, try to use `allowUnknownKeys = true` for the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory`. And read more in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-session-factory).

Comment: Thanks a lot.I am working on the java config with Sftp provided thru the link.However for the bean MessageSource<InputStream>  exception is: The type org.springframework.integration.file.remote.AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
  referenced from required .class files.I am using spring integration core 4.3.1 Release version in gradle

Comment: Bean definition :  @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "stream")
    public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource() {
        SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template(), null);
        messageSource.setRemoteDirectory("sftpSource/");
        messageSource.setFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(),
                           "streaming" ));
        return messageSource;
    }

Comment: Only `core`? The `AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource` is a part of `spring-integration-file`. You have to upgrade all modules to the same version. Or even better just use `spring-integration-bom` to manage all the version in the same place.

Comment: Please, don't provide code in the comments. That is fully not readable. Just edit your question and comment it there. The StackTrace would be useful as well.

Comment: Ok.I have added the code.Please provide with ur comments as  i am still facing the same issue

Comment: Please, find an EDIT in my answer. Although that is fully different story and doesn't relate to the `read file without copying` question...

Comment: Thank you for pointing my mistake.I removed the core dependency and kept only file and sftp 4.3.1 release dependencies.The exception went away but  started giving error for the Inboundchanneladapter and Transformer annotations

Comment: I could finally remove all the errors.I added value instead of channel in the inboundchanneladapter and problem got resolved.But its now giving  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EXPRESSION_PARSER exception

Comment: Can u please help in this ?

Comment: I still think that you have some mix with the versions. Consider to rely only on the Spring Boot. And exactly the last 1.4 version. And show stack trace for that exception . We can't help you for just to words from there. Remember, we a thousand similar question on SO to answer ?

Comment: I understand.I have added stack trace and updated dependencies.

Comment: I added spring integration core 4.3.1 dependency as it was needed for StreamTransformer.But now its giving the exception as in the stack trace.I tried to specify the pattern to match all text files but dint find any direct method to do so.

Comment: I have been able to remove the error.Latest code above is now working.It was giving the error because of a missing /  while setting remote directory.So i had to put / before test1.Thanks Artem.Your response helped me a lot.

Comment: I would only like to knwo the significance of the word "Streaming " used in the filter .It as such did not prevent file from reading at my end.But for knowledge purpose i would like to know

Comment: This code works fine when run on local.But if I push it to PCF ,then the sftpSessionFactory  times out.Can u please tell what can be the reason for the failure ? @ArtemBilan

Comment: Please, find an EDIT2 in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Artem! The file read was restricted because the port was blocked due to firewall.I had doubt reagrding the word "streaming' in messageSource.setFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(),
                           "streaming") .I want to know its significance.

Comment: The `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` ctor second arg is a `prefix` for shared `MetadataStore`. To distinguish keys from each other, if several component has access to the same `MetadataStore`:

Comment: Can you please help me with how to delete the  remote file after read using the above code.With xml,I found attributes that can be set to true/false to delete the remote file but with above java configuration I cant find any method that can delete the remote file.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look `delete-remote-files` is for regular synchronization adapter. The `streaming` adapter emits exactly **Stream** for remote file. Therefore it can't remove them. You can achieve that using `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE` header, which is `Session` with `remove()` operation and `REMOTE_DIRECTORY` & `REMOTE_FILE`, respectively.